# Draw Text Along A Line Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can i draw a text along the side of a pentagon or a triangle like in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Real answer

You can't.
It is a current feature request on the Flutter Github (See [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16477)). However it's not yet implemented and I can't find anywhere specifying a date.

### Possible solution / Workaround

1. Draw the image on a graphic editor like Photoshop.
2. Draw letter by letter with translations and rotation as done in [this article](https://developers.mews.com/flutter-how-to-draw-text-along-arc/).